# trying to compare object cannot use IF statement JAVA

Tags: java, object, if-statement, arraylist, boolean

I am writing a method to find an object in an ArrayList. If I can find the object I will print it out to the screen, otherwise I will print an error message saying "Object not found". The problem I am running into is since my method is the object, "Dodecahedron", and not a boolean, I cannot use an if statement to compare if the object exists in the array. How else could I approach this?

This is the code in my main method.

```
    System.out.print("\tLabel: ");
    label = userInput.nextLine();

    if(myDList.findDodecahedron(label)) {

        System.out.print(myDList.findDodecahedron(label));
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("\t\"" + label + "\" not found");
    }
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter Code [R, P, S, A, D, F, E, or Q]: ");
    break;
```

and this is my method.

```
public Dodecahedron findDodecahedron(String label1In) {
      String label = "";
      String color = "";
      double edge = 0;
      Dodecahedron result = new Dodecahedron(label, color, edge);
      int index = -1;
      for (Dodecahedron d : dList) {
         if (d.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(label1In)) { 
            index = dList.indexOf(d);
            break;
         }    
      }
      if (index >= 0) {
         dList.get(index);
         result = dList.get(index);
      }
      return result;
   }
```

And this is the error I get when I try to compile.

```
DodecahedronListAppMenu.java:99: error: incompatible types: Dodecahedron cannot be converted to boolean
               if(myDList.findDodecahedron(label)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the return value is null.

```
if (myDList.findDodecahedron(label) != null)
```

You'll need to update `findDodecahedron()` to return null if it doesn't find anything, rather than a new object. Changing the initial value of `result` will do that:

```
Dodecahedron result = null;
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of `index` and `result` if you just return the shape immediately when you find it. No need to save its index off and then look the index up after the loop ends.

```
public Dodecahedron findDodecahedron(String label1In) {
   for (Dodecahedron d : dList) {
      if (d.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(label1In)) { 
         return d;
      }    
   }
   return null;
}
```

You might also streamline it a bit further with Java 8 streams:

```
public Dodecahedron findDodecahedron(String label1In) {
   return dList.stream()
      .filter(d -> d.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(label1In))
      .findAny()
      .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method doesn't return a boolean but a specific object you should assign it into a variable to exploit it. 
You don't instantiate a specific object and return it to test it like a boolean value.  And because of that, you have to repeat the method invocation to retrieve a second time the result as you need to print it in the std output. 
It is helpless and a duplicate code/processing.

This should look like :

```
Dodecahedron obj = myDList.findDodecahedron(label)
if(obj != null) {
    System.out.print(obj);
}
else {
    System.out.print("\t\"" + label + "\" not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially implementing the [null object design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) here. You can make this explicit in the `findDodecahedron` method (side note - I replaced the implementation with Java 8-style streams for elegance, but it's not really required):

```
public static final Dodecahedron NULL_DODECAHEDRON = new Dodecahedron("", "", 0);
public Dodecahedron findDodecahedron(String label1In) {
      return dList.stream()
                  .filter(d -> d.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(label1In))
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(NULL_DODECAHEDRON);
}
```

And then use it in the if condition:

```
if (!myDList.findDodecahedron(label).equals(NULL_DODECAHEDRON)) {
    System.out.print(myDList.findDodecahedron(label));
} else {
    System.out.print("\t\"" + label + "\" not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't call the find method twice. Assign the result to a local variable for reuse.

Multiple choices:

1. Since you create a *dummy* object with empty label, which is returned if not found, you can check for that.

   ```
   Dodecahedron result = myDList.findDodecahedron(label);
   if (result.getLabel().isEmpty()) {
       System.out.print("\t\"" + label + "\" not found");
   } else {
       System.out.print(result);
   }
   ```

   Alternative is the [null object design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) described in [answer by Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52543022/5221149).
2. Change method to return `null` for not found.

   ```
   public Dodecahedron findDodecahedron(String label1In) {
       for (Dodecahedron d : dList) {
           if (d.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(label1In)) {
               return d;
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   Use:

   ```
   Dodecahedron result = myDList.findDodecahedron(label);
   if (result != null) {
       System.out.print(result);
   } else {
       System.out.print("\t\"" + label + "\" not found");
   }
   ```
3. Change method to return `Optional` (Java 8+).

   ```
   public Optional<Dodecahedron> findDodecahedron(String label1In) {
       for (Dodecahedron d : dList) {
           if (d.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(label1In)) {
               return Optional.of(d);
           }
       }
       return Optional.empty();
   }
   ```

   Alternative for returning `Optional` is the use of streams.

   ```
   public Optional<Dodecahedron> findDodecahedron(String label1In) {
       return dList.stream()
                   .filter(d -> d.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(label1In))
                   .findFirst();
   }
   ```

   Use:

   ```
   Optional<Dodecahedron> result = myDList.findDodecahedron(label);
   if (result.isPresent()) {
       System.out.print(result.get());
   } else {
       System.out.print("\t\"" + label + "\" not found");
   }
   ```

Option 3 using streams is the recommended solution.